# How to set final static variable values in a component by reading the values from fragment?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, osgi-fragment

I am just beginner in OSGi and we are still using version 4.
I have a OSGi component where one of the class has public static final (psf) variables.

What I would like to do, I want to use a fragment where it reads the values from properties file and set the values of the psf variables in the component. ? If the fragment is not found, values should be set to default.

Please find my snapshot code and let me know how can i do this ?

Component class

```
public final class OdsPrincipals {
   /*****************************************************************************************
    * Static/Inner class members
    ******************************************************************************************/

   private static final String ODS_PRODUCT_NAME;
   private static final String ODS_PRINCIPAL_NAME;

   static {
         //How to set the values of static final variables.
   }
```

fragment class

```
public class OdsPrincipalProperties {

   /*'***************************************************************************************
   *   Static/Inner class members                                         
   ******************************************************************************************/

   protected static final String ODS_PRINCIPAL_PROPERTIES_FILE = "odsprincipal.properties";

   private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

   static {
      try {
         properties.load(
               OdsPrincipalProperties.class.getResourceAsStream(ODS_PRINCIPAL_PROPERTIES_FILE));
      } catch (Exception e) {
         ServiceLogger.error(e);
      } finally {
      }
   }

   private static final OdsPrincipalProperties odsPrincipalProperties = new OdsPrincipalProperties();

   public static OdsPrincipalProperties getInstance() {
      return odsPrincipalProperties;
   }

   /*'***************************************************************************************
   *   Class members                                         
   ******************************************************************************************/

   protected OdsPrincipalProperties() {
   }

   /*
    * returns the value for a given key. If the key is not 
    * found, returns the default value.
    * 
    */

   public String getValue(String key, String defaultValue) {
      return properties.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set so called *compile time constants* at *runtime*. That is by definition not possible. The reason is that at *compile time* every occurrence of the variable in your code is replaced with the value of the constant. So even if you could change them at *runtime* the rest of your compiled code would not be updated.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i found the other way to fix the problem.